# ActionScript http request

Tags: request, flash, http, actionscript

Суть вопроса, можно ли сформировать свой header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Документацию](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequestHeader.html#includeExamplesSummary) смотрели? Пример оттуда:

```
    public function URLRequestHeaderExample() {
        loader = new URLLoader();
        configureListeners(loader);

        var header:URLRequestHeader = new URLRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("http://www.[yourdomain].com/greeting.cfm");
        request.data = new URLVariables("name=John+Doe");
        request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;
        request.requestHeaders.push(header);
        try {
            loader.load(request);
        } catch (error:Error) {
            trace("Unable to load requested document.");
        }
    }
```

Comment: да, только можно ли изменить допустим юзер агента?

Comment: юзер агент задается не через заголовки, а как свойство URLRequest'а. [URLRequest.userAgent](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html)

Comment: Заголовки можно устанавливать любые, кроме:

>Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ranges, Age, Allow, Allowed, Authorization, Charge-To, Connect, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-Range, Cookie, Date, Delete, ETag, Expect, Get, Head, Host, If-Modified-Since, Keep-Alive, Last-Modified, Location, Max-Forwards, Options, Origin, Post, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Connection, Public, Put, Range, Referer, Request-Range, Retry-After, Server, TE, Trace, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, Upgrade, URI, User-Agent, Vary, Via, Warning, WWW-Authenticate, x-flash-version

Comment: Благодарсвую